# AngularJS : ng-repeat not working fine

Tags: php, angularjs

i want a list of links as in code

Here is my code:

```
 <div ng-repeat="s in CPS" class="dropdown-content">

  <a class='activation' 
    href='javascript:void(0)' 
    data-value='update_status_active.php?sr_id={{s.id}}' 
    data-toggle='modal' 
    data-target='#activation'>

    {{s.name}}

   </a>

</div>
```

There are 10 record in "CPs"
but i am getting a single link based on the value of last record in "CPs"

what's  the issue?

JSON array :

```
 $scope.CPs=
 [
      { "id" : 1, "name" : "user1"},
      { "id" : 2, "name" : "user1"},
      { "id" : 3, "name" : "user1"},
      { "id" : 4, "name" : "user1"},
      { "id" : 5, "name" : "user1"},
      { "id" : 6, "name" : "user1"},
      { "id" : 7, "name" : "user1"},
      { "id" : 8, "name" : "user1"},
      { "id" : 9, "name" : "user1"},
      { "id" : 10,"name" : "user1"}
  ];
```

Comment: could you post CPS array ?

Comment: i have posted above

Comment: so you've typed CPS instead of CPs

Comment: i have changed but it has the same issue,even i have removed the browser cache

Comment: check my answer below please!

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your code. It should be CP**s** instead of CP**S** in your `ng-repeat`

```
 <div ng-repeat="s in CPs" class="dropdown-content">

  <a class='activation' 
    href='javascript:void(0)' 
    data-value='update_status_active.php?sr_id={{s.id}}' 
    data-toggle='modal' 
    data-target='#activation'>

    {{s.name}}

   </a>

</div>
```

Comment: what kind of typo i have?

Comment: @mubsher I have updated my answer with the typo info

Comment: i have changed but it has the same issue,even i have removed the browser cache

Comment: there is no error in my console,i think a custom directive should be made for this purpose,but dnt know  how!

Answer (score 0):

here is a working exmaple

```js
angular.module('myApp',[]).controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
  $scope.CPs=
   [
        { "id" : 1, "name" : "user1"},
        { "id" : 2, "name" : "user1"},
        { "id" : 3, "name" : "user1"},
        { "id" : 4, "name" : "user1"},
        { "id" : 5, "name" : "user1"},
        { "id" : 6, "name" : "user1"},
        { "id" : 7, "name" : "user1"},
        { "id" : 8, "name" : "user1"},
        { "id" : 9, "name" : "user1"},
        { "id" : 10,"name" : "user1"}
    ];
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<div ng-repeat="s in CPs" class="dropdown-content">

  <a class='activation' 
    href='javascript:void(0)' 
    data-value='update_status_active.php?sr_id={{s.id}}' 
    data-toggle='modal' 
    data-target='#activation'>

    {{s.name}}

   </a>

</div>
</div>
```